# Django template rendering relational modelobject names without duplicates

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys, django-queryset

So I have been trying to figure out how to render related objects in a template. I have been trying to do it with the query-set in the template, but i might be totally wrong and I need to do something with the context instead. Either way I have no idea what I'm supposed to do.

What i want to do:

Get a query-set with the tips that are going to be published.

With the help of the query-set render a list of tips for the city. The list itself is the station and the number of tips for said station and the total number of tips for the specific region.

What i want to render in my template

```
Uptown (3)
   K-Jah (2)
   Chatterbox FM (1)

Staunton Island (1)
   Lips 106 (1)
```

What i have been trying with:

```
<table>
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <th>Region</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ object.station.region }} </td>
    <tr>
        <th>Station</th>
        <td>{{ object.station.name }}</td>

    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now this is clearly wrong and I know it. It loops over and renders the same region and station name several times and I don't render the number of times a region or station appears in the loop.

I have my models setup like below:

models.py

```
class Tip(models.Model):

    name = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('name'), blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_('email'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('description'), blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('published'))

class NamedModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('name'), max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.name

class Region(NamedModel):

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % self.name

class Station(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('name'), max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('phone'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, verbose_name=_('region'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name


class StationTip(Tip):
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, verbose_name=_('station'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.school
```

The query-set:

K-Jah region = Uptown

Chatterbox region = Uptown

Lips 106 region = Staunton Island

```
StationTip.objects.all().filter(published=True)
```

What the query-set returns:

```
[<StationTip: K-Jah>, <StationTip: K-Jah>, <StationTip: Lips 106>, <StationTip: Chatterbox FM>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is the [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) function in combination with the `values` function:

```
from django.db.models import Count
tips = StationTip.objects.filter(published=True).values('station__name', 'station__region').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

This will create a list with a dictionary for each unique combination of `station.name` and `station.region`, with an extra key `count` and the number of occurrences.

And in your template (if you pass tips as object_list):

```
<table>
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>Station</th>
        <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ object.station__region}} </td>
        <td>{{ object.station__name }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.count }}</td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea how annotation worked, definitely something i will use again later on.